# React native Webview Wait for data from external API the response url load as string

Tags: node.js, react-native, webview

React native Webview Wait for data from external API the response url load as string..

```
<WebView
        source={{uri:'http://192.168.59.153:3000/api/v1/common/paymentsuccess?order_id=XO1703698968731&status=AUTHORIZATION_FAILED&status_id=27&signature=5%2BoeQbQBvNymRYNrh6%2BIMuCJSbYmXhTzOw8X7qUx20Q%3D&signature_algorithm=HMAC-SHA256'}}
        style={{flex: 1}}
        injectedJavaScript={injectedJavaScript}
        onMessage={handleMessages}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
  onError={(error) => console.error('WebView Error:', error)}
  onLoad={() => console.log('WebView Loaded')}
      />
```

```
This is react native Code the responce of this api 'http://192.168.59.153:3000/api/v1/common/paymentsuccess?order_id=XO1703698968731&status=AUTHORIZATION_FAILED&status_id=27&signature=5%2BoeQbQBvNymRYNrh6%2BIMuCJSbYmXhTzOw8X7qUx20Q%3D&signature_algorithm=HMAC-SHA256' are 'https://www.xopay.in/Failed.html?status=PaymentFailedmsgtestt'
```

```
let Stripe = async (req, res) => {
return res.status(200).json(`https://www.xopay.in/Failed.html?status=PaymentFailedmsgtestt`);
}
```

but its load as a string i need load the page

[image]